# Javascript, how can I access a specific child of a row?

Tags: javascript, html-table, row

Using Javascript, how can I access a specific child of a row?
Javascript (not jQuery please).

e.g.: second `<TD>` of `<TR>` where ID=id33322010100167

```
<table>
<tr id="id33322010100167">
<td>20101001</td>
<td>918</td>
<td>919</td>
<td>67</td>
<td>CAR PROBLEM</td>
</tr>
<tr id="id33322010100169">
<td>20102001</td>
<td>913</td>
<td>914</td>
<td>62</td>
<td>LUNCHTIME</td>
</tr>
<table>
```

Comment: you have a problem here, your two `tr` element have the same `id` value!

Comment: no jquery. must work on blackberry, jquery doesn't (yet). Also fixed the <tr> elements

Comment: Your accepted answer doesn't work in non-IE browsers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var index = 1; // second element
var child = document.getElementById('id33322010100167').childNodes[index]
```

Comment: Have you tried this? This returns the first `<td>`, not the second, because the first child node of the `<tr>` is a text node containing whitespace.

Comment: No, it isn't. `document.getElementById('id33322010100167').childNodes[2]` will give another whitespace node. Also, what if the OP then removed all the line breaks in his source code? That preserves the order of `<td>` elements while completely changing the `childNodes` collection.

Comment: It also gives different results in IE from other browsers, since IE doesn't consider the whitespace nodes in `childNodes` whereas other browsers do.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you can try this:

```
var tRow = document.getElementById("tableName").getElementsByTagName("tr");

for(var i = 0; i < tRow.length; i++){
    if(tRow[i].id == "name of your id"){
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: The other issue is that there are no ids in the `<td>` elements in the example and the OP may not want to have to add them.

Answer (score 2):

I found this solution in combining the two most rated one:

Instead of using childNodes you could get Elements of typ td below this row with:

```
var array_td = document.getElementById('id33322010100167').getElementsByTagName("td");
```

To get the content of the first td you could use:

```
array_td[1]
```

The main benefit of this is, that you do not have all the whitespace you dont want to handle inside the array and you dont have to change the index if some new childs (not tds) be added.

Answer (score 1):

Most reliable is the `cells` collection, which unlike `childNodes` in non-IE browsers will ignore whitespace text nodes between cells:

```
var td = document.getElementById("id33322010100167").cells[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the DOM you can get the table and then iterate over the child elements while keeping count.

Of course element ids are supposed to be unique so that `document.getElementById('id')` works.

Answer (score 0):

Use [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/):

```
first = $('#id33322010100167 td:first'); // gives you the first td of the tr with id id33322010100167 
last = $('#id33322010100167 td:last'); // gives you the last td of the tr with id id33322010100167
```

you may use next() to iterate through the elements

```
first.next();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table id="studTable" class="table table-bordered">
     <thead>
        <tr>
           <td>Click</td>
        </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
           <tr><td><a href="#" onclick="ClickRow(this)">Click</a></td></tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

for above table you can use something link this. you can read your selected row by clicking row/cell inside row and read cell values and/or remove row from table

```
function ClickRow(r) {
        console.log(r.parentNode.parentNode.cells[0].innerHTML); //Read First Cell in Row
        var i = r.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
        document.getElementById("studTable").deleteRow(i); //Remove Row
    }
```